# How to reactively update widgets that are using Controller's function to compute private value

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

1. Assume I have a widget, in which I'm doing some basic computation.
2. And I have a getx controller, in which I have a function, that takes a value, and do some computation on it (based on a private observable inside this controller)
3. I'm calling the controller's function inside my widget, with the computation I have performed
4. when I update the controller's private observable value, the widget does not get updated reactively (`Widget1` in the code below)

For widget to update reactively, the only way I can find is to supply the function of the controller directly to the widget as a parameter. I don't want to do this, for the following reasons:

- I would have to do the computation outside of the widget (and this computation is simple ones like adding a currency symbol next to the text and etc. So it makes sense to me to widget being responsible of small manipulations)
- the widget itself is a nested widget, so I'd have to relay this argument throughout all the nested calls, again, very ugly API

Is there a way to somehow notify this widget so that it can rebuild itself when the observable changes?

Here is the minimal reproducible example (the logic does not make sense in the below code, but just replicated the issue):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import "package:get/get.dart";

class MyController extends GetxController {
  final _private = 0.obs;

  String multiplyString(String value) {
    return (value * _private.value);
  }

  void incrementPrivate() {
    _private.value += 1;
    _private.refresh();
  }

  void resetPrivate() {
    _private.value = 0;
  }
}

class MyStruct {
  final String field1;
  final String field2;

  MyStruct(this.field1, this.field2);
}

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Get.put(MyController());
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final myStruct = MyStruct("a", "b");

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            MyWidget(myStruct: myStruct),
            // Obx(() => const Widget2()),
            /*
            cannot use `Obx` here, it creates the error `incorrect usage of Obx`
             */

            const IncrementButton(), // silly button, don't mind this
            const ResetButton(), // silly button don't mind this
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final MyStruct myStruct;
  const MyWidget({Key? key, required this.myStruct}) : super(key: key);
  // assume this is a call to a complex nested widget:
  // Widget1 will build many widgets inside of it
  // and there will be lot's of variables generated by the computation, not a single one
  // but for simplicity, I did not involve the nested widgets and other variables

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MyController myController = Get.find<MyController>();
    String _computation = myStruct.field1 + myStruct.field2;

    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Using controller\'s func to compute private value: ${myController.multiplyString(_computation)}',
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class IncrementButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const IncrementButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MyController myController = Get.find<MyController>();
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              myController.incrementPrivate();
            },
            child: const Text("press this to increment private by 1"))
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ResetButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const ResetButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MyController myController = Get.find<MyController>();
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              myController.resetPrivate();
            },
            child: const Text("press this to reset private"))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Basically what I'm looking for is, finding a way to somehow notify this widget so that it can rebuild itself when the observable changes.